# .htaccess URL redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect http://domain.com/blog/index.php/weblog/rss_2.0/ to http://www.domain.com/feed/ with .htaccess?

The website has 3 domains pointing to it and all is using the same htaccess.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could utilise mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/index\.php/weblog/rss_2\.0/$ /feed/ [R=302]
```

That should forward the URL to /feed/ on the same domain as the request came in on. Once you're happy it's working you can change the 302 to 301.

Answer (score 4):

```
redirect 301 blog/index.php/weblog/rss_2.0/ http://www.domain.com/feed/
```

It's that easy!  Just make sure that the .htaccess file is located at the web root, which is usually `http://www.domain.com'.

**EDIT:** For redirecting other pages, just follow the basic format

```
redirect 301 [path from web root] [full path to the new page]
```

You can add another line for every page that you want to redirect.

Comment: thanks for this. but I forgot to mention it has 3 domains pointing to it and using the same htaccess.

Comment: @steamboy You can add another line for every page you want redirected.  Just follow the format that I added to the answer, and you should be all set.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use RedirectMatch directive of Mod-alias to redirect a url from location to another.

forexample : to redirect 
from http://example.com/file.php to http://example.com/folder/file.php

You would use the following code in htaccess :

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^.]+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1.php
```

Explaination :
RedirectMatch directive uses regular expression pattern to match against the url path. in the example above our pattern **^/([^.]+).php$** matches against the url path **/file.php** , **^** means start of line. then we match **/** , **([^.]+)** is a capture group it matches any characters excluding dot ,and saves the value as $1 for reuse in target url, in the example above it captures name of file. **.php** matches **.php** litterly. we need to ecape the dot with a back slash because it is a special word in regex. **$** means end of line/string.