# .htaccess redirect conflicts with another htaccess rule that I can not remove

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

### **The Information:**

So I am fairly new to .htaccess and have being reading a bit.

Basically I want to do this, redirect the url **www.example.com/center-pro** to **www.example.com/pro-hq** 
(found how here here [.htaccess URL redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374696/htaccess-url-redirect))

However the site i am work on already has a .htaccess file in place.

This is what I am adding doing :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  #already in htaccess file
RewriteEngine On         #already in htaccess file

Redirect 301 /center-pro http://www.example.com/pro-hq    #line I added


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   #already in htaccess file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   #already in htaccess file
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?idstring=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}   #already in htaccess file
```

The last line seems to be messing with my redirect

So the output from my redirect looks like this :
**www.example.com/pro-hq?idstring=center-pro**

### **The Question:**

Is there any way to have the redirect rule above and keep the current .htaccees so I don't mess up the current site settings.

** note: Doing a RewriteRule works but i would like to use a redirect so people don't share the wrong url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrite` for your external redirection too:

```
RewriteRule ^center-pro$ http://www.example.com/pro-hq [R=301,L]
```

This is probably the simplest solution, in place of your current `Redirect`. The problem is that `mod_rewrite` performs its work before `mod_alias`, and while the rewritten URI path is not passed along, the modified query string unfortunately is. You could also condition your `RewriteRule` to prevent it from processing the path you want handled by `mod_alias`, but I prefer the first option:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/center-pro
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?idstring=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Additionally, for your current`RewriteRule`, you can just use the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) flag instead of manually appending the query string to the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?idstring=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Awesome I tired doing a RewriteRule (RewriteRule center-pro pro-hq [L]) before, but the url was just being mask, seems like by adding R=301 the url is changed!

The first line worked great, thanks for the depth of info, not going to change to the QSA flag as i didnt write that line.

Now I need to go learn what ^ and $ do in htaccess land.

Thanks Again

Comment: @theGoose - No problem. As far as the `^` and `$` go, they're just [regular expression anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the test patterns, and match the beginning and the end of the input (the current URL without the query string), respectively.