# How to rewrite a subdomain with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a subdomain like this:

```
Example: http://us.example.com/index.php?city=newyork
```

How do I rewrite to:

```
http://us.example.com/newyork
```

"us" is a virtual subdomain. So, It can be different: us, fr, it, etc..

I tried in this way but it does not work

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?city=$1
```

Comment: i hope this link will help you  [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374696/htaccess-url-redirect

Comment: http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-htaccess.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?city=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?city=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?city=([^&]+)&ountry=([^\s&]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?city=$1&country=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Great!It's perfect! if I want to add another parameter for example:
from http://us.example.com/index.php?city=newyork&country=usa to http://us.example.com/newyork/usa  How can I do?

Comment: Thank you so much anubhava! 
but I have forgot to tell you that the second parameter must be not obligatory. I have no words to thank you enough!

Comment: like this work: http://us.example.com/newyork/usa
instead like this does not work: http://us.example.com/newyork

The second parameter in this case "usa" must be optional

Comment: It should work, did you combine both set of rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: Sorry anubhava, I made a mistake :-) ..Everything is fine! Thank you sooo much!!