# .htaccess redirect using GET parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have already checked a lot of answers related to .htaccess redirecting, but yet I was unable to elaborate my problem:

I have an old website with blog entries addressed like this:

**http://ellrohir.mzf.cz/index.php?page=blog&id=77**

Now I also have a new website with "nice urls" where blog entries can be found using:

**http://alois-seckar.cz/politics-blog/77**

I want to "shut down" the old page and redirect any old links to new site. How to catch and transfer the old url to the new url? I still cannot figure the necessary .htaccess code up :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess URL redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374696/htaccess-url-redirect)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://alois-seckar.cz/politics-%1/%2? [NC,L,R]
```

Empty question mark at the end is important to discard the orignal query strings from the destination url.

%n is part of the regex in RewriteCond, it's the part matched between ([ and  ]+).

This rule will redirect

```
example.com/index.php?page=foo&id=bar
```

to

```
example2.com/politics-foo/bar
```

Comment: This one is great!

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect to another website using `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/index.php?page=blog&id=(.*)?$ http://example.com /politics-blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: for me, this one didn't do anything :(