# Forward domain & port with masking

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, port, mod-proxy

So I'd like to use a htaccess file to forward a domain:port onto another domain:port

In this case I'll use this example of what I want to achieve

```
DomainA.co.uk --> DomainB.co.uk
DomainA.co.uk/* --> DomainB/*
DomainA.co.uk:8000/* --> DomainB:8000/*
```

even better would be able to forward any and all ports on like so

```
DomainA.co.uk:*/* --> DomainB:*/*
```

Thoughts would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Henry

Addition : The OS i am running is cPannel/WHM 60.8 on CentOS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess URL redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374696/htaccess-url-redirect)

Comment: @jas_raj slightly different I believe due to the ports. I could do a standard redirect on the domain with wildcards, but the ports issue throws a spanner in the works...

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting a domain wholesale can be achieved with directive [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

```
Redirect / http://DomainB.co.uk
```

or to domain B with port 8000

```
Redirect / http://DomainB.co.uk:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following RewriteRule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ http://domainB.com:%{SERVER_PORT}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```