# Redirect a web page URL to another website

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a simple PHP website. Let's call it *youtubex.com*. I want to redirect youtubex URLs (in the format shown on STEP2) to my website in the format shown on STEP3. Here, I am using YouTube, just for illustration.

```
STEP1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj62iuaKAhU
STEP2: https://www.youtubex.com/watch?v=lj62iuaKAhU 
STEP3: https://www.youtubex.com/#url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj62iuaKAhU
```

STEP1 shows any desired URL. STEP2 shows the same URL from STEP1 with youtubex as domain. STEP3 shows the final required URL. I am trying to redirect STEP2 to STEP3.

I tried finding some solutions to this on the internet and SO, but, none help. Here is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374696/htaccess-url-redirect).

Comment: what is the point of step 3 when you can get the VIDEO ID from step 2? STEP 3 doesn't make any sense

Comment: Actually, STEP3 is the final step (required URL). My objective is if someone visits STEP2 URL, it should redirect to STEP3.

Comment: why do you want to do that ? would https://www.youtubex.com/#url=lj62iuaKAhU also do the trick ?

Comment: No, https://www.youtubex.com/#url=lj62iuaKAhU will not work @pooya-estakhri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /watch$ https://www.youtubex.com/#url=https://www.youtube.com/watch
```

Comment: @MrWhite thanks for pointing out, my mistake. I have corrected the mistake. :)

Comment: Nice simple solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

An inefficient but full php solution can be using the location header in php :

```
    $vid = $_GET['v']
    if($vid){  header("location:https://www.youtubex.com/#url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$vid");
    }
```

by the way you can't get the text after the hash mark in php because it is not sent to the server.

javascript can do it in a more neat way without the second reload by checking `window.location.href` to see if the hash does not exist already and then [get the v parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript) in url then change url without refreshing the page by using `window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", urlPath);`

Answer (score 2):

using php str_replace and header :

```
$step2_url = "https://www.youtubex.com/watch?v=lj62iuaKAhU";
$part2_url = str_replace("youtubex","youtube",$step2_url);//the output is : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj62iuaKAhU
$step3_url = "https://www.youtubex.com/#url=".$part2_url; //the output is : https://www.youtubex.com/#url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lj62iuaKAhU
```

now you have the final url , simply redirect

```
header($step3_url);
```